# How to hide label if something is in input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

First name

```css
#Start+ #DITBT {
  position: absolute;
  top:5px;
  right:1160px;
  left: 15px;-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;  }
#Start:focus + #DITBT {
 opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-field"> 
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="Start" maxlength="30" class="pad" required /> 
  <label for="Start" id="DITBT">First name</label>
</div>
```

How to hide label if something is in input value

Comment: Add your HTML in the code snippet please.

Comment: <div class="input-field">
<input type="text"    name="firstname" id="Start"  maxlength="30" class="pad" required />
 <label for="Start" id="DITBT">First name</label></div>

Comment: When do you want to hide your label ?

Comment: if input value is more than 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input').on('input',function(){
   if($(this).val() != '') {
        $(this).parent().find('label').fadeOut();   
   } else {
       $(this).parent().find('label').fadeIn(); 
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nwdrrnun/2/

Comment: HTML attributes are preferred to use, unless you don't have any other option, because Java Script slows page loading time. 7 Lines in your Java Script code, could be 1 line in HTML !

Comment: He is asking about hiding LABEL, not placeholder, and you can't style placeholder ...

Comment: There is nothing called "you can't" in programming. Of course you can style a placeholder, read:
http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder-css
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-css3-placeholder-pseudo-element

Answer (score 3):

```css
input::placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}

input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-field"> 
  <input type="text" placeholder="placeholder" name="firstname" id="Start" maxlength="30" class="pad" required /> 
  <label for="Start" id="DITBT">First name</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
#Start:focus + #DITBT {
 opacity:0;
}
```

With

```
#Start:focus + #DITBT {
 display:none;
}
```